# Python: Normalising a histogram - Y values don't range from 0 to 1

Tags: python

I am trying to make a normalised histogram with the area under the bins equal to 1 and also having the probability on the y-axis ranging from 0 to 1.

Using **ax.hist()** and setting **density=True**. I am able to generate the histogram with the sum of the area equal to 1, but the y axis doesn't hold
[image: Histogram from the data]

Histogram code:
`ax.hist(data1[1],  bins=b, histtype = 'step',alpha = 0.8, color= 'gray', linestyle='-', facecolor='gray', fill=True, linewidth=0, zorder=8)`

Normalising the histogram gives the second plot above
[image]

Normalised histogram code:
`ax.hist(data1[1],  bins=b, histtype = 'step', density=True, alpha = 0.8, color= 'gray', linestyle='-', facecolor='gray', fill=True, linewidth=0, zorder=8)`

Notedly, the y-axis exceeds 1 which I don't expect to obtain. How best can this be resolved so that the total area under the bins is 1 but the y-axis shows the probability with a maximum of 1?

Comment: You cannot have **both** the total area under the bins to be equal to 1 **and** the maximum probability equal to 1, unless you change the values on the X axis, which probably does not make sense to your data representation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to normalize the values on the Y axis, and have the sum of the bar heights summing to 1, you can do the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123) # for reproducibility

# Normal data in the [1.00, 1.10] interval
data = np.random.randn(100)
data = (data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min()) * 0.10 + 1.00
print(data.min(), data.max())
b = 6


plt.figure()
n, __, __ = plt.hist(data,  
                    bins=b, 
                    histtype = 'step', 
                    density=True, 
                    alpha = 0.8, 
                    color= 'gray', 
                    linestyle='-', 
                    facecolor='gray', 
                    fill=True, 
                    linewidth=0, 
                    zorder=8
                    )
plt.yticks(ticks = np.linspace(0.0, n.sum(), 11),
           labels = [round(i / 10, 1) for i in range(11)]
           )

plt.show()
```

[image: The generated histogram]

Please note that the sum of the *area* under the bins does not sum to 1, as it also depend on the bin width. Anyway, the sum of the *bar heights* sums to 1, which I believe might be what you were asking for.

Hope this helps!